# Prove from first principles: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2+2n-2}{n^2-6}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove using $\epsilon - n_0$:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2+2n-2}{n^2-6}=1$$ 
I made an attempt on this question but I'm not sure if this is the correct path.

Firstly I did
$\frac{n^2+2n-2}{n^2-6}-1$ < $\epsilon$ ?

after that  |$\frac{n^2+2n-2}{n^2-6}-1$| = |$\frac{2(n+2)}{n^2-6}$| which =|$\frac{2n+4}{n^2-6}$|.

What do I do after this?

Would $n\geq3$ due to making the denominator positive?

$$n\geq 3 \implies 2n\geq6 \implies 2n+4  \geq  10 > 0$$

Are these steps correct?

Comment: Questions about $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs belong to real analysis. "Proof theory" is something entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(2n+4)(n-\frac32)=2n^2+n-6>n^2-6$

Then for $n>3/2$ we have that

$$\left|\frac{2(n+2)}{n^2-6}\right|< \frac{2n+4}{(2n+4)(n-3/2)}=\frac1{n-3/2}<\epsilon$$
for an $n>3/2$ large enough.

Comment: How did you get $(n-\frac32)$?

Comment: I needed a suitable way to cancel out the $2n+4$, so I sought for a suitable polynomial larger than $n^2-6$